# can not replace path using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, associative-array

i have this part of a code which finds and replaces strings from an associative array, the script is working when it is replacing strings but it is not working when the string is path.

```html
#!/bin/bash
tomcatDirName="tomcat801"
tomcatSvcName="tomcatSvc"
tomcatSvcUser="tomcatUsr"
tomcatSvcGrp="tomcatGrp"
installationPath="/opt/app"
tomcatDirPath="$installationPath/$tomcatDirName"
initDTomcatFilePath="/root/scripts/tomcat801"
javaDirName="java"
javaDirPath="$installationPath/$javaDirName"
jdkDirPath="$javaDirPath/jdk1.8.0_45"


declare -A TomcatInitD=(
 ["^CATALINA_HOME.*"]="CATALINA_HOME=$tomcatDirPath"
 ["^TOMCAT_USER.*"]="TOMCAT_USER=$tomcatSvcUser"
 ["^TOMCAT_SVC.*"]="TOMCAT_SVC=$tomcatSvcName"
 ["^JAVA_PATH.*"]="JAVA_PATH=$jdkDirPath"
)

for i in "${!TomcatInitD[@]}"
do
 value="${TomcatInitD[$i]}"
 key="$i"
 sed -i -e "s/$key/$value/" $initDTomcatFilePath
done
```

i am getting 2 lines of error on the 2 paths that i am trying to replace them.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 35: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unknown option to `s'
```

can any one tell me whats wrong or how to do it, many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your associative array is using `/` in paths and your `sed` command is also using `/` as regex delimiter you are getting this error.

You can change your `sed` to use an alternative delimiter:

```
for i in "${!TomcatInitD[@]}"
do
    value="${TomcatInitD[$i]}"
    key="$i"
    sed -i -e "s~$key~$value~" $initDTomcatFilePath
done
```